# How to avoid ReenterTransition when returning from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, material-design, android-transitions

I've got a little problem. My navigation schematic looks like this:

[image: nav schema]

These 4 fragments are equal and navigated between with a nav drawer. details_dest is a fragment opened from the RecyclerView using shared element transition. Everythings works, but **when i go back from details_dest, my reenter transition of list_dest is played**. I want to avoid that, how can I do this?

Setting it null in the fragment won't help since I need it when navigating from other fragments.

The onClick listener of my recycler view is set up in the adapter and calls a navigation method in the fragment.

In adapter's onBindViewHolder:

```
holder.view.setOnClickListener {
        fragment.onItemClick(holder.view, data[position])
    }
```

In previous fragment:

```
fun onItemClick(cardView: View, alcoObject: AlcoObject) {
        val rowAlcoholDetailsTransitionName = getString(R.string.row_alcohol_details_transition_name)
        val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(cardView
                to rowAlcoholDetailsTransitionName)
        val directions = MenuFragmentDirections.openDetails(alcoObject)
        findNavController().navigate(directions, extras)
    }
```

Comment: Can you post how you handle opening and closing fragments?

Comment: Yeah, I edited the question @Ali Eid.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but if your main fragments are part of the main activity ( view pager inside this activity ) , then you can ```add``` the details fragment instead of ```replace```.

Comment: Any way, i upvoted your question and hope you get a helping hand.

Comment: The problem is i'm not handling it with supportFragmentManager but with Navigation Components. Well, technically it should be ```added``` not ```replaced``` but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Did you try searching Stack Overflow for a similar issue?

Comment: yeah, found nothing. Think I'll just use fragment manager here